# ZeroMQ - .lib file missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, zeromq

ZeroMQ's [downloadable](https://zeromq.org/download/) archive (.zip) for windows comes with 3 types of files:

1. Application files (look like test files)
2. dlls (libsodium and libzmq)
3. zmq.h (the public header)

How do I go about statically linking these in my visual studio project on Windows 10 (x64)? Historically, they've provided .lib files for that purpose, but i can't seem to find them in their [historical downloads](http://download.zeromq.org/) either anymore.

I'm not keen on using [LoadLibrary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya), but is it the only way around this missing .lib now?

Comment: You may be able to build it yourself with `vcpkg`. There is  a port for that: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/zeromq

Comment: That's definitely a bug in the way the binaries are provided. Please open an issue under https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues

Comment: The contributors created a PR for the issue I opened on August 20

https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/pull/3639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo owners have re-published binaries with .lib files for version 4.3.2 in their [downloads](https://zeromq.org/download/) section.

Hopefully, the same for [older versions](http://download.zeromq.org/) will follow suit.